# How to select students for teachers automatically in Django

Tags: python, django, web, django-models, web-development-server

This is my students class

```
class Students(AbstractUser):
    mobile_number = models.TextField()
```

My Teacher Class

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    students = models.TextField()
```

How can associate 6 students to one teacher automatically in Django

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your models.
If every student can have only one teacher then you need to change Student model this way:

```
class Student(AbstractUser): 
    mobile_number = models.TextField()
    teacher = models.ForeignKey("Teacher", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

and then you can assign teacher to student like this
`teacher = Teacher.objects.get(pk=...) #get required teacher`
to assign this teacher to several students you can
`Student.objects.filter(pk__in=[id_student1, id_student2, ...]).update(teacher=teacher)`

if you want to assign any number of students, then in place where you "hire" teacher you need to do, find required number of students which doesn't have any teacher, then assign teacher to them. you can do it this way:

```
for student in Students.filter(teacher__isnull=True)[:6]:
   student.teacher = teacher #where teacher is your hired teacher
   student.save()
```

if your student can have multiple teachers then you need to use ManyToMany relationships (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

```
class Student(AbstractUser):
    mobile_number = models.TextField()
    teacher = models.ManyToManyField("Teacher", related_name="students")
```

and to assign several students to one teacher you can:

```
student1 = Student.objects.get(pk=...)
student2 = Student.objects.get(pk=...)
...
teacher.students.set([student1, student2, ...]) # this will replace all students with selected
teacher.students.add([student1, student2, ...]) # this will add selected students to other students connected with this teacher
```

Comment: Actually I want one teacher to have at max 6 students to teach and give them homework

Comment: as i said earlier in answer you can chooce any variant you want with ForeignKey(if 1 student can't have many teachers) and ManyToManyField if one student can have several teachers

Comment: Ok, then how can we add students to teachers automatically means students get distributed to all Teachers
like if there are 12 students we will hire 2 teachers and they will automatically get 6 students without adding from admin

Comment: Forgot to add `student.save()`. if everything is fine now, can you accept my answer?

Comment: Yeah how to do it tell me

Comment: near `up` and `down` buttons(at the beginning of my answer) should be button, that allows you to accept this answer

Comment: I am doing but it says Something like

Comment: ""

Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.
"

Comment: One more thing how to retrieve all data in django manytomany field

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Can you also answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63601050/manytomany-field-refere-to-itself