# ManyToMany Field Refere to Itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

How can make my model so that its ManyToMany Refer to User

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    teacher_or_student = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    laptop_yes_or = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `'self'` string for this. By default a `ManyToManyField` that refers to itself, is als *symmetrical*, so you probably want to turn that off, since if *a* is a student of *b*, then *b* is not per se a student of *a*. You can do that by specifying [**`symmetrical=False`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical):

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    teacher_or_student = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    laptop_yes_or = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        symmetrical=False,
        related_name='teachers'
    )
```